# omxplayer (sound) hangs

Tags: audio, omxplayer

I did a simple alert script in `bash`. On my RPi `nc`listens on some port. When somebody (some other RPi or PC) sends a message to this port, `nc` finishes and `omxplayer` **plays a sound**. Then the loop repeats. What have looked easy, appeared to be a problem when it should run many months without a hangup. I have solved a rare hangup of `nc` (by a timer with cyclic kill and restart `nc` within a script).

But what I cannot solve is that **omxplayer rarely hangs** when supposed to play a sound (approx. once a week) and `kill -9 omxplayer.bin` does not help. I tried `mpg321` instead and I ended with the same problem, maybe a little more frequent.

One thing I observed - when I managed to kill the `omxplayer.bin` process (by killing the parent), all the sounds that were waiting (I mean that were sent to the soundcard after) were played immediately one by one.

Answer (score 1):

i've had this problem, and solved it by adding the '`--no-keys`' option to the omxplayer commandline.

Not ideal (you lose kb control over the player), but at least it doesn't hang anymore...